# This application is not licensed. Please purchase it from Android Market in android

Tags: android

i uploded my app with google license with correct key but when i download the app from store it gives

"**This application is not licensed. Please purchase it from Android Market.**"

***here is the code:***

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY = my_app_key;

    // Generate your own 20 random bytes, and put them here.
    private static final byte[] SALT = new byte[] {
        -46, 35, 30, -128, -103, -57, 74, -64, 51, 88, -95, -45, 67, -117, -36, -113, -11, 82, -44,
        29
    };

    private TextView mStatusText;

    private LicenseCheckerCallback mLicenseCheckerCallback;
    private LicenseChecker mChecker;
    // A handler on the UI thread.
    private Handler mHandler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
        setContentView(R.layout.license);

        mStatusText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.status_text);

        mHandler = new Handler();

        // Try to use more data here. ANDROID_ID is a single point of attack.
        String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

        // Library calls this when it's done.
        mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
        // Construct the LicenseChecker with a policy.
        mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
            this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
                new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
            BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
        doCheck();
    }

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        final boolean bRetry = id == 1;
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(R.string.unlicensed_dialog_title)
            .setMessage(bRetry ? R.string.unlicensed_dialog_retry_body : R.string.unlicensed_dialog_body)
            .setPositiveButton(bRetry ? R.string.retry_button : R.string.buy_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                boolean mRetry = bRetry;
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    if ( mRetry ) {
                        doCheck();
                    } else {
                        Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                                "http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                            startActivity(marketIntent);                        
                    }
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.quit_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            }).create();
    }

    private void doCheck() {

        setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
        mStatusText.setText(R.string.checking_license);
        mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
    }

    private void displayResult(final String result) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                mStatusText.setText(result);
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

            }
        });
    }

    private void displayDialog(final boolean showRetry) {
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
                showDialog(showRetry ? 1 : 0);

            }
        });
    }    

    private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
        public void allow(int policyReason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // Should allow user access.
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,first.class));
        }

        public void dontAllow(int policyReason) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            displayResult(getString(R.string.dont_allow));
            // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
            // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
            // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
            // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
            // restricted set of features.
            // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to Market.
            // If the reason for the lack of license is that the service is
            // unavailable or there is another problem, we display a
            // retry button on the dialog and a different message.
            displayDialog(policyReason == Policy.RETRY);
        }

        public void applicationError(int errorCode) {
            if (isFinishing()) {
                // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
                return;
            }
            // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
            // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
            // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
            String result = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
            displayResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mChecker.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

Comment: hello, i am facing same issue in apk expansion file download,if you resolved  this issue Please post solution, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the same id that you uploaded it with?